# Function that returns strings matching in different lists

Tags: python

I am new to Python, so apologies in advance if my question seems foolish.

I am trying to build a function that searches for strings of a list inside the strings of another list and returns all matching words. More specifically, I am trying to check if certain key words I compiled in 2 lists (poa_corporate_identifier / poa_cnpj_identifier) are located in my text list below.

For some reason I keep receiving a single string as output, when I know there are more items inside my key words lists that are also inside certain strings of my text list.

Can anyone help me to identify why is my code not giving the expected result (or suggest another efficient way to achieve my goal)?

Thanks in advance!

```
text = ['power of attorney',
'(b) to attend any partners’ meeting; (c) to represent the grantor 
regarding any change or amendment to the articles of association; (c) to 
receive service of process on behalf of the grantor in the event of 
judicial proceedings arising from applicable corporate laws in brazil; (d) 
to represent the grantor before the central bank of brazil; (e) to 
represent the grantor before the brazilian federal revenue office; (f) to 
deal and solve any issues before the brazilian federal revenue office, and 
to sign any document before that agency including, but not limited to, the 
basic cnpj entry document',
'in witness whereof, grantor has caused this document to be executed by 
its chief executive officer, mr. [?], in the city of [•], on this [•] day 
of [•], [•].']

poa_corporate_identifier = ['articles of association', "partners' 
meeting", "shareholders meeting", 'corporate laws', 'corporate books', 
'board of commerce']
poa_cnpj_identifier = ['brazilian federal revenue office', 'cnpj', 'basic 
cnpj entry document']
poa_nature = poa_corporate_identifier + poa_cnpj_identifier

def term_tracker(document, term_variations):
    if isinstance(term_variations, list) == True:
        for term in term_variations:
            if any([str(term) in i for i in document]) == True:
                return term              
    if any([term_variations in i for i in document]) == True:
        return term_variations
    else:
        print('No term located')
```

Comment: How do you call `term_tracker`, what are the arguments?

Comment: calling the function in this way: term_tracker(text, poa_nature)

Comment: I'm not sure that this is where you got confused, but the return inside the for loop will only ever return one thing. If you want to return multiple words, you need to collect them in some way, something like `return [term for term in term_variations if any([str(term) in i for i in document])]` (assuming you really need to convert term into string)

Comment: What I thought, you need to return a list of terms! But you only returning the first matched element! check my answer below @gcqhk19

Comment: thanks guys, @Devesh Jumar Singh 's suggestion worked!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are returning the first term you match via `return term`, instead you need to append all terms you matched in the document list, into a terms list, and then return that list

Also you need to check if term variations is a string for the next case, and finally you don't need the last else, you return your terms list always

```
def term_tracker(document, term_variations):

    terms = []
    #If term variations is a list
    if isinstance(term_variations, list) == True:
        for term in term_variations:
            #If we find a term in the document, append that term to a list
            if any([str(term) in i for i in document]):
                terms.append(term)

    #If it is a string, find that string in all documents
    elif isinstance(term_variations, str) == True:
        if any([term_variations in i for i in document]) == True:
            terms.append(term_variations)

    return terms

print(term_tracker(text, poa_nature))
print(term_tracker(text, 'cnpj'))
```

The output will be

```
['articles of association', 'corporate laws', 'brazilian federal revenue office', 'cnpj', 'basic cnpj entry document']
['cnpj']
```

Comment: Great, it worked perfectly! Thanks for the prompt response @Devesh Jumar Singh!!

Comment: Great! Glad to help @gcqhk19 ! If the answer helped you, please consider accepting it by clicking the tick next to it :) Please also consider taking a look at stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers :)

Comment: Thanks for the accept @gcqhk19 :) Have a great day :)

Comment: another question for you, can I replicate your solution if my term_variations variable is a dictionary? I tried this:

```
def term_tracker(document, term_variations):
    terms = []
    
    #If term_variations is a dictionary
    if isinstance(term_variations, dict) == True:
       for term in term_variations:
            if any([str(term) in i for i in document]):
                terms.append(term)
```

For this I am getting an empty list as output!

Comment: Why not make another question for it @gcqhk19 This way I can answer your question more clearly :)

Comment: here you go @Devesh Kumar Singh : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56070503/how-to-build-a-function-that-returns-elements-matching-in-txt-file-and-dictiona

Answer (score 0):

Change your function to below.

```
def term_tracker(document, term_variations):
    if isinstance(term_variations, list):
        return [term for term in term_variations if len([i for i in document if term in i])]
    elif len([i for i in document if term_variations in i]):
        return term_variations
    else:
        print('No term located')
```

Since it wasnt returning the list so you were just getting single value.

```
['articles of association',
 'corporate laws',
 'brazilian federal revenue office',
 'cnpj',
 'basic cnpj entry document']
```

Comment: Thanks @satyam soni, but for some reason I keep getting the following error while running your suggestion:

Comment: ----> 3         return [term for term in term_variations if any([i for i in document if 
    term in i])]
    .
    .
    .
    -> 2013     return _wrapreduction(a, np.logical_or, 'any', axis, None, out, 
    keepdims=keepdims)
    .
    .
    .
         81                 return reduction(axis=axis, out=out, **passkwargs)
         82 
    ---> 83     return ufunc.reduce(obj, axis, dtype, out, **passkwargs)
         84 
         85 
         TypeError: cannot perform reduce with flexible type

Comment: try using len in place of any, would filter out all the counts except 0