# How to build a function that returns elements matching in txt. file and dictionary

Tags: python

I am new to Python, so apologies in advance if my question seems foolish.

I am trying to build a function that searches for keys and values of a nested dictionary (built from info in a csv file) inside a .txt file and returns all matching words. So far this is what I tried:

```
text = ['da#8970095-v4',
 'd#30/04/2019',
 'h#2.0',
 'power of attorney']

clientlist = {'hong kong co.': {'Client Code': '897',
  'Matter Code': '0095',
  'Matter Name': 'Incorporation of Brazilian Subsidiary'},
 'shanghai co.': {'Client Code': '965',
  'Matter Code': '3569',
  'Matter Name': 'Corporate Matters'}}


def term_tracker(document, term_variations):
    terms = []

    #If term_variations is a dictionary
    if isinstance(term_variations, dict) == True:
        for term in term_variations:
            if any([str(term) in i for i in document]):
                terms.append(term)

    #If term_variations is a list
    if isinstance(term_variations, list) == True:
        for term in term_variations:
            #If we find a term in the document, append that term to a list
            if any([str(term) in i for i in document]):
                terms.append(term)

    return terms
```

For some reason my output is a blank list:

```
In: term_tracker(text, clientlist[clientname]) #text = .txt file
Out: []
```

I could build lists with information collected from my nested dictionary (e.g., only with keys, or only with values), but I am trying to keep my code as clean as possible and therefore want to avoid this.

The following is another part of my code that I am also having issues with. When I use my term_tracker function inside the client_summary variable and then try to write a .txt file with the information included in this variable, my .txt file comes out without the information that the function should return.

```
def string_cleaner(document):
    document = document.replace('[', '')
    document = document.replace(']', '')
    document = document.replace("'", '')
    document = document.replace('"', '')
    return document

for documents in samples:
    filename = 'Time Sheet-' + time.strftime("%Y%m%d-%H%M%S")
    infile = open(path + 'Sample docs' + '/' + documents, 'r')
.
.
. 
    client_summary = ['Client: ' + str(term_tracker(text, clientlist[clientname]['Client Code']))]
    client_summary = string_cleaner(str(client_summary))                

    outfile = open(path+'Automated work descriptions/'+filename,'w', encoding='utf-8')
    outfile.write(client_summary)
    outfile.close()
```

If I run client_summary my editor returns the output I want. However, this information is not being written in my .txt file. I assume this has to do with the problem I am having with my function because if I try the following alternative I get the information I want written in a .txt file:

```
client_codes_only = [val['Client Code'] for val in clientlist.values()]
>>> ['897', '965']
.
.
.
        client_summary = ['Client: ' + str(term_tracker(text, client_codes_only))]
        client_summary = string_cleaner(str(client_summary))
>>> 'Client: 965'
```

Can anyone help me to identify why is my code not giving the expected result (or suggest another efficient way to achieve my goal)?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Could you provide a couple rows of the data? (as well as "document").  If your term_variations is not a list and not a dictionary, you're going to get back the empty list.

Comment: In fact, if your subsequent if-statements aren't satisfied, you're going to return an empty list.  You could add things to catch and alert to this.  Psuedocode: if empty list, return 'nothing found'

Comment: edited my question to include some data

Comment: use `print()` in function to see values in variables - it helps to see where can be problem. OR learn how to use debuger.

Comment: Based on data given function should return empty list right? I can’t see matching term

Comment: @Andrew Allen, there are terms inside the first string of text variable matching Client Code and Matter Code values inside the nested dictionary!

Answer (score 0):

Your script is returning the key of the dictionary, and you want the values.

Substitute this:

```
if any([str(term_variations[term]) in i for i in document]):
```

Wherever you have "term" replace it with term_variations[term].

It's worth noting, that your logic matches '0095', in your example data, with 'da#8970095-v4' in your "text" list.

2nd part of question:

For starters, if Hong Kong Co is your client lookup, then this line of code: `client_summary = ['Client: ' + str(term_tracker(text, clientlist[clientname]['Client Code']))]`
is passing term_tracker(text,'897') into your function, which will return the empty list from term_tracker(). Which will then write nothing to your file.

Comment: for reading about this topic see https://www.pythonforbeginners.com/basics/list-comprehensions-in-python and https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html

Comment: @ColinMac, great! First part of my question solved, the editor returns the expected result ('3569', '965'].

However, still have the issue with blank information when running the chunk of code that writes the info in my .txt file.  This:

```
    client_summary = ['Client: ' + str(term_tracker(text, clientlist[clientname]['Client Code']))]
    client_summary = string_cleaner(str(client_summary))                

    outfile = open(path+'Automated work descriptions/'+filename,'w', encoding='utf-8')
    outfile.write(client_summary)
    outfile.close()
```
writes this: Client:

Comment: When I run term_tracker(text, clientlist[clientname]['Client Code']) it does not return an empty list, but rather '897', which is what I was expecting. However, what I am struggling to understand is why this information is not being written into my .txt file i.e., my client_summary is written in my .txt file as "Client: "

Comment: When I run: """clientname = 'hong kong co.'
print('2: ', str(term_tracker(text, clientlist[clientname]['Client Code'])))"""  I get an empty list

Comment: What do you want client_summary to be for example 'hong kong co.'?